# negation of an implication, preserving implication

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can one distribute the not for the following statement: 
$ \lnot (p \implies q)$

I have come up with this:
$p \land \lnot q$

I'm pretty sure this is correct (please tell me if it isn't!), but is there a way to distribute the not and preserve the implication?

Comment: what you got is correct because $p \implies q \equiv \neg p \vee q$.

Comment: You have $\neg (p \to q)$. This is true exactly when $p \to q$ is false. And by definition of $\to$, an implication is false precisely when the antecedent is true and the consequent is false, i.e. $p$ is true and $\neg q$ is true, that is when $p \wedge \neg q$ is true.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

**Implication**

$P \rightarrow Q = \neg P \lor Q$

Thus:

$$\neg (P \rightarrow Q) = \neg (\neg P \lor Q) = \neg \neg P \land Q = P \land \neg Q$$

p.s. I know that may textbooks use the $\Rightarrow$ for material implication, but prefer to use $\rightarrow$ for the material implication, since many logicians use $\Rightarrow$ represent *logical* implication.

Comment: Hi, I only have few logic books, so I haven't seen an author use $\rightarrow$ and $\Rightarrow$ in the same book, not to say distinguish them. Do you mean some authors use $\Rightarrow$ to mean $\vDash$?

Comment: @Eric Yes, exactly, though the $\Rightarrow$ is often between two sentences (e.g. $P \land Q \Rightarrow P$: $P \land Q$ logically implies $P$)), while the $\vDash$ is typically between a set of sentences and a sentence (e.g. $\{ P, P \rightarrow Q \} \vDash Q$).  Note that you also get that for any two sentences $\varphi$ and $\psi$: $\varphi \Leftrightarrow \psi$ if and only if $\varphi \Rightarrow \psi$ and $\psi \Leftrightarrow \varphi$, i.e. Two sentences are logically equivalent if and only if they logically imply each other, so that's a nice result.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup
\newcommand{\degs}{^\circ}
\newcommand{\cut}{\, \backslash \,}
\newcommand{\AND}{\ \ {\rm{\small{AND}}}\ \ }
\newcommand{\OR}{\ \ {\rm{\small{OR}}}\ \ }
\newcommand{\NOT}{\ \ {\rm{\small{NOT}}}\ \ }
\newcommand{\Implies}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\If}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\Iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\x}{\times}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} \newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}} \newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}} \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} \newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\rm{\small{E}}}}
\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}} \renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\dash}{\textrm{-}}
\newcommand{\der}{\partial}
\newcommand{\del}{\nabla}
\newcommand{\inv}{{\sim}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\indent}{\ \ \ \ \ \ } \newcommand{\dedent}{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}$
What you have written is correct. A standard way to define $p \Implies q$ is
$$ p \Implies q := \neg p \lor q $$
Therefore by De Morgan's and the Double-Negation Laws:
\begin{align}
\neg(p \Implies q) &\equiv \neg(\neg p) \land \neg q \\
&\equiv p \land \neg q
\end{align}
As for the second part of your question, the short answer is No. There is no meaningful way to express $\neg(p \Implies q)$ as an implication itself. This is because an implication (or material implication) is defined as a *disjunction*, i.e. an OR statement. Hence its negation is a *conjunction*: an AND statement. And an AND statement is fundamentally different from an OR statement, and cannot be "rearranged" into an OR statement to fit the definition of the implication.

To put it another way, an implication is a statement that tells you that *if* something is true, then something else is true. It doesn't tell you *whether* any constituent statement *inside* the implication is true, but tells you that one of them is true *in the event that* the other is true.

But if you look at the negation $p \land \neg q$, there is nothing "iffy" about it. In fact, since it is a conjunction, it tells you the truth value of *both* constituent statements (i.e. $p$ is true and $q$ is false). Therefore it fundamentally differs from the logical form of an implication.
$\endgroup$